# Update sibling Views position during animation in a wrapped container (tried many methods. Still not achieving its intended effect)

Tags: android

Say we have the below vertical LinearLayout (`WRAP_CONTENT` on both layout width and height) with two childs Button with varying height.

```
{ LinearLayout
  * empty space *
   |          |
   | Button 1 |
   |__________| 
   |Button 2|   }
```

Why animating Button 1 "y" using ObjectAnimator, producing this:

```
{ LinearLayout
   |          |
   | Button 1 |
   |__________| 
  * empty space *
   |Button 2|   }
```

hence leaving a space there instead of moving Button2 below Button1 as well?

As for the code (nothing fancy): `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button1, "y", delta).start();`

1. I tried using ValueAnimator (with `setY` in `OnAnimationUpdate()` and then upon seeing the same thing,
2. Setting LinearLayout to invalidate during `OnAnimationUpdate()` also did the same thing.
3. tried with TranslateAnimation with fillEnabled and fillAfter being true. Both still producing this behavior.

What am I missing here? I have used LayoutAnimation but so far, I only used to animate them if a child is added or removed. Not if their bounds change.

Can anyone clue me in to the right method/terms here (or the correct way to achieve this effect)?

Note that I also actually wanted Button1 to be clipped by the parent container, if I animate beyond the parent bounds (though I not sure if it makes any difference for Button2). English isn't my first language so pardon the grammar or terms. Thanks.

Comment: Are you (or have you tried to) animating the Button2's `y` as well, through `setY`?

Comment: Well I'm not intended to do that since Button2 is just arbitrary object there. What if I have lots of varied size Buttons below Button1? Hence the question for the "correct" implementation since animating the rest of the childs instead seems... kinda roundabout way to go about it? Unless that's the only way of course.

Comment: You could have an empty dummy view between button 1 and button 2 with height 0, and then animate it's height along with the y of button1.